How to copy/transfer tasks from one Windows 10 machine to another
I have a windows 10 machine (A) where all the task files under Windows\System32\Tasks\Microsoft got erased due to a hard disk corruption. Now because all the default windows tasks missing, many services are having issues.
I have another identical machine (B) also running Windows 10. So I went and copied the entire Microsoft folder from the tasks folder of the working B machine to the tasks folder of the original corrupted A machine.
Now I can see all the default windows tasks in the Tasks\Microsoft folder in windows explorer of the A machine, but when I start Task Scheduler it doesn't show any tasks. I've tried to reset the permission to allow Administrators and current users etc to full permissions but even after rebooting I cannot see any of the tasks in Task scheduler.
Is there a way to transfer all tasks from the Tasks\Microsoft folder from one machine to another?
Is there a way to get Task scheduler to show these tasks that are copied between machines?

There is also a registry component. HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Schedule\Taskcache and HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Schedule\Tasks

While I'm still waiting for an answer but here's some information that helped me partially:

Use a script like this to manually create each task from an Administrative command prompt given the directory which contains all the tasks copied from Machine B (in the c:\tmp\Tasks directory). This worked partially but I guess my task database was so corrupted that it kept giving me an Access denied issue when trying to create the task (I couldn't even import the task manually from the Task scheduler at this point).

@echo off
set d=C:\tmp\Tasks
chcp 65001>nul
for /f "usebackq delims=|" %%f in (`dir /b /s /a-d "%d%"`) do (
  schtasks /create /tn "%%~nxf" /xml "%%~f"
)


I use this tool called Repair Tasks version 3.3 from here. I opened this tool with Administrative access, did a Scan on my tasks and it gave me a whole bunch of missing tasks. Then I selected Repair with Take tasks from backup option selected, it prompted me for the directory which the tasks and I pointed it to the folder of tasks I had copied from machine B. This also wasn't perfect, at first it gave me a whole bunch of Access is denied errors (similar to option 1 above). But then I re-ran the tool a bunch of times and eventually it recreated the missing tasks from the backup folder. Now this didn't get me what I wanted, create all the copied tasks, it only recreated those tasks in it's database that were missing from the Tasks folder. So partial success again.

